One Up 8x8 puzzle
Rodolfo Kurchan created a wonderful new grid puzzle called One Up that you can play on his website. There is one main rule:
Each horizontal and vertical sequence of N cells between walls, must contain every number between 1 and N, in some order.
For example, here are the possible sequences in the following grid:
 
Here is puzzle #39 from Rodolfo's collection. Some cells have already been filled. Can you solve it? The solution is unique.


Final grid:

 

Obvious deductions:

 

More obvious deductions:

 

Continuing:

 
 The solution of this column will prove to be crucial.

Wrapping things up gives:

 


I apologize profusely in advance for my... aggressive marking practices.

Wow you sniped me by a long shot, how did you solve it so quickly!

thank you :) probly my agressive marking

Just an addendum to the solution above.
Silly, but I first missed that singles can be filled with 1's, so I started in a completely different but imho interesting way.

 Since there are no 6- or 7-lines, all 6's, 7's and 8's must be at the intersection of 8-lines.  If you mark them you quickly see they must all be filled.  This leads to a number of easy deductions.




 If then you mark the cells that can be 5, the intersections of a 5-lines with a 5- or 8-lines, you can easily place a number of 5's.



 With this start (and finally placing the single 1's) the rest can be solved without much difficulty.


Ahem https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/126301/62272 please read the comments

I disagree with that comment.  I believe the path to the solution is much more interesting than the solution itself.
